# Jquery minimum range slider - type error

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jquery slider. I have checked that jQuery and Jquery ui are loaded, but i get an error which is

TypeError: jQuery("#slider-range-min").slider

The code for slider is

```
jQuery(function() {

    //var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();    
        jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 37,
            min: 1,
            max: 700,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "jQuery" + ui.value );
            }
        });
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "jQuery" + jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
    </script>
    <p>
    <label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

I have copied the code from jquery ui site, just replaced $ with jQuery. '$' is not loaded, so i have to use 'jQuery'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the JQuery scripts libraries you've included . Some of them are either missing or not included correctly so make sure you've included these in `<head></head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```